# Flutter - How to get error code line : "Another exception was thrown"

Tags: debugging, flutter, dart, runtime-error

When I run my application, I get an error:
Another exception was thrown: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

My android screen immediately red with the error above, but only a few moments. After that back to normal. What I want to ask is, how can I know which line is error?

[image]

Comment: This message means that the stacktrace for that error was already printed, because it's the same error again. You may need to scroll up and find the first ocurrence of that error, maybe search for 'type string is not a subtype of type int of inded'.

Answer (score 0):

are there any values on your code that could be null at some point in time?
like if you are getting a price try to give that value except for null.

if something is like this:

```
Text(price);
```

change it to:

```
Text(price !=null ? 'your price' : "nothing!")
```

in the picture I see a null value, maybe that's causing the problem. you can also put prints on your code to track that down. you should also check the beginning of errors. that might help too!